# ES6 Dynamic Import is failing when the file imports another named export

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a file called `a.js`:

`a.js`:

```
import { set } from 'lodash';
import { myFunc } from '../helpers';

export default 'hello';
```

Then I am dynamically importing the above file (`a.js`) in `b.js`:

```
const aFile = await import('a.js');
```

When I webpack the files above I get errors such as: `Can't resolve 'fs'`, `Can't resolve 'cldr'`, `Can't resolve 'cldr/supplemental'`, `Can't resolve 'cldr/event'`, `Can't resolve 'cldr/supplemental'`, `Can't resolve 'net'`, `Can't resolve 'dns'`.

But when I remove the `import { myFunc } from '../helpers';` from `a.js`, the webpack runs perfectly fine. I am positive the path `../helpers` exists and `myFunc` is a named export in the `../helpers` file.

Why is it that when I remove that line webpack build passes but otherwise it fails?

Comment: Does helpers.js import fs, cldr, etc.?

Comment: Oh that's a good point. My helpers.js file is importing a lot of other modules which might be importing fs, cldr, etc. I moved the `myFunc` from 'helpers` to a separate file and it works now. Thanks a lot! You can add your answer as an answer and I can accept it.

Comment: Okay I went ahead and wrote an answer and what I would have suggested afterwards. Best of luck. Webpack is very difficult to configure in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if helpers.js file is importing fs, cldr, etc. Try moving myFunc from `helpers.js` to a separate file and see if that fixes the issue.

If that doesn't fix the issue try specifying `target: 'node'` in your wepback config like so:

```
target: 'node',
node: {
  fs: 'empty',
  net: 'empty',
  ...
  dns: 'empty',
}
```

The target: 'node' option tells webpack not to touch any built-in modules like fs or net. I'm not sure why, but adding the `'empty'` strings seems to fix `Can't resolve` errors as well, depending on your configuration.

See this article: https://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I
And github issue: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447#issuecomment-285600188

I ran into similar issues and this seemed to help me resolve the issue. Webpack is tricky.